# How is maximum memory defined during Webassembly.instantiate?

Tags: javascript, memory, webassembly

Instantiation:

```
const res = await WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBuf, {});
```

Memory Declaration:

```
const memory = res.instance.exports.memory as WebAssembly.Memory;
```

**How is the `memory` object's [maximum](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory) set, how do I specify memory maximum, and/or how do I change it after instantiation?**

Note, currently when I try `memory.grow()` I get the following error

```
Uncaught RangeError: WebAssembly.Memory.grow(): Maximum memory size exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Defined at compile time](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/72d6ae302df110ca02244a1e89ddf6d59993cd55/src/settings.js#L191), add the following to `emcc` compile options as command line arguments

```
// allow memory.grow()
-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 \

// change default memory size
-s INITIAL_MEMORY=1000000
```

More detail:

Whelp.... I guess I just needed to ask the question, been looking for an hour now, and find the answer 5 minutes after I post:

Seems WebAssembly adopts the `memory` specifications within the `.wasm` file, which are defined at compile time by `emcc`.

Comment: If you would rather have the memory defined at runtime (and/or defined in JavaScript) you can use the `-s IMPORTED_MEMORY` option. 

The default is that memory is defined in the wasm file with its max fixed at build time.